# Error parsing external XML data as html with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to parse an external xml and I'm having trouble trying to get the info as html across supported browsers. Using dataType: 'html' works fine in everything but IE7 & IE8, where it does nothing.

Using dataType: 'xml' would work fine for getting data using .text() afterwards, but I need the html formatting inside the xml nodes. Console throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined." on everybrowser when I try using .html() on a dataType: 'xml'.

How can I solve this issue?

Here is my setup:

I load the external .xml via ajax like this

```
var data_fill;
var $xml = $.ajax({
url: 'negocios.xml',
dataType: 'html',
success: function(data){
    data_fill = data;
},
error: function(data){
    console.log('Error loading XML data');
}
});
```

The general structure of the XML is:

```
<directorio>

<tabs-df>

    <negocio rel="100natural">
        <url>100natural.com</url>
        <promo_info>Sucursales participantes: <br /><b>Insurgentes y Metepec</b></promo_info>
        <legales>Vigente al 30 de septiembre de 2014. <br />Válido al pagar con The Gold Elite Credit Card American Express<sup>®</sup><br /> o con The Platinum Credit Card American Express<sup>®</sup>.<br />Válido en restaurantes a partir de las 14 hrs. al cierre. No aplica en fast food. <br />No aplica con otras promociones o descuentos.<br /> Consulta sucursales participantes.<br /> Se deberá solicitar el descuento al pedir la cuenta.
        </legales>
    </negocio>

</tabs-df>
```

Then I build a popup parsing the xml with this function:

```
function fill_popup($target,$group){
var $xml_node = $($group,data_fill);  
$($xml_node).find("negocio[rel='"+$target+"']").each(function () {
        $url = $(this).find('url').text();
        $legales = $(this).find('legales').html();
});
console.log($legales);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot return a value like that from an ajax request....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your HTML in the 'cdata' "wrapper".

```
<tabs-df>

    <negocio rel="100natural">
        <url>100natural.com</url>
        <promo_info><![CDATA[Sucursales participantes: <br /><b>Insurgentes y Metepec</b>]]></promo_info>
        <legales><![CDATA[Vigente al 30 de septiembre de 2014. <br />Válido al pagar con The Gold Elite Credit Card American Express<sup>®</sup><br /> o con The Platinum Credit Card American Express<sup>®</sup>.<br />Válido en restaurantes a partir de las 14 hrs. al cierre. No aplica en fast food. <br />No aplica con otras promociones o descuentos.<br /> Consulta sucursales participantes.<br /> Se deberá solicitar el descuento al pedir la cuenta.]]></legales>
    </negocio>

</tabs-df>
```

Read more here... http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Yeah! That was exactly the problem, I should use this: <![CDATA[<p>This goes in the Product Description area</p>]]> Thanks!